# How do I remove Javascript dialog console box seen in Chrome?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, javascript, java-applet

Windows XP using Chrome, I have javascript or java applet console box that runs in the right hand corner of the sidebar which is a Dialog box. Tabs say "execute JS, "hide console" "show source". Opens every time I start chrome. It's at right and at bottom slider, and extremely irritating.

How do I remove it?

Comment: Can yo provide a screen shot please?

Comment: Seems that you have the [JavaScript Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-console/ohpmcainjdkbnkmkfmfbadfljaogedna) extension installed? You can remove it in "Preferences - Extensions"

Answer (score 0):

Go to the URL `chrome://extensions/` from within Chrome and disable anything you don't want running.  You should see the Javascript tool on that list.